# Why do some middleware need to be registered with `ConfigureServices` while others don't?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, middleware

I have two middleware in my ASP.NET Core application. One needs to be registered with `ConfigureServcies`, but the other one doesn't.

For example:

1.

```
public class RequestMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public RequestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(httpContext);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // ... code ...
            }
        }
   }

// I use this middleware in startup
app.UseMiddleware<RequestMiddleware>();
```

2. ```
   public class SampleMiddleware : IMiddleware 
   {

       public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
       {
           // ... code ...
       }
   } 

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddTransient<AppSampleLogsMiddleware>();
   }
   app.UseMiddleware<AppSampleLogsMiddleware>();
   ```

Why does the second one need to be registered, but not the first one? How are they different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second way of creating middleware is called [Factory-based Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/extensibility)

> `UseMiddleware` extension methods check if a middleware's registered type implements `IMiddleware`. If it does, the `IMiddlewareFactory` instance registered in the container is used to resolve the `IMiddleware` implementation instead of using the convention-based middleware activation logic. The middleware is registered as a scoped or transient service in the app's service container.
>
> Benefits:
>
> - Activation per client request (injection of scoped services) Strong
> - typing of middleware

So, because of implementing the `IMiddleware`, not only do you need to add this middleware to the request pipeline, but you also need to register it into DI containers.

This subtle difference has to do with scope. Factory-based middleware are transient and can receive scoped services via the constructor. See the [Creating conventional and factory-based Middleware for .NET Core](https://codingdistilled.medium.com/creating-conventional-and-factory-based-middleware-for-net-core-a36751187ca3) post to learn more.